# How to get fullscreen browser on multiple screens

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, multiple-monitors, browser

I am setting up a PC that will have 3 touch screens that is meant to display one web page stretched across all 3 screens. I've noticed that when using the chrome or firefox full-screen mode (F11) it will lock the browser into only being on 1 screen. How can I get this full screen "Kiosk-ish" browser mode to stretch across all 3 screens. Or alternatively is there some other browser I could try that supports having no on screen controls (fullscreen mode) and is able to do so while stretched across multiple screens?

I have tried using AMD Eyefinity display group to "trick" the OS into seeing only 1 very large screen, and visually this does get the job done. But the problem is that the touch screens do not play nicely with this mode and the touches do not register to the proper locations.